# How to navigate between two screens in flutter and show keyboard?

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I have some next (simplified) widget-tree structures:

```
- home (stack of widgets)
  - page container
  - editText field
```

As you can see, edit text will be always on top of the pages, which I will swap with `Navigator.of(context)` transactions.

**The problem:** when I focus `editText` the keyboard appears. When user starts typing, at some moment, I need to push another screen inside the `page container`. And when I use `Navigator.of()` - `editText` is unfocused and the keyboard goes down.

**Whats needed:** I need somehow to do transition (push/pop/replace) in `page container` with the `Navigator` and keep keyboard still up (keep editText focused).

Do you have any knowledge of how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do but try giving the TextField a GlobalKey (created inside a Widget State).

Comment: @Lulupointu thank you for your try... but no, it is didn't helped.

Comment: Then I think I would need a small reproducible example if I was to help you

Comment: @Lulupointu sure, here it is https://github.com/pro100svitlo/test_edit_text_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case looks really weird but I suppose you have a good reason to follow this setup.

Anyway the issue is that when `Navigator.push` is called, the `TextField` is unfocused. This is not a bug but rather an intended feature which (I think) is here to prevent a keyboard to follow you to the next screen where no `TextField` would be present. However I understand that this is an issue for your use case.

My solution (not the prettiest I would admit, but the only thing I could have working) is to force the focus back to the `TextField` manually. You need two component:

- A `FocusNode` to associate to your `TextField` to listen to check if your `TextField` changes from focus to unfocused. If the `focusOnNextUnfocus` is set, it should re-request the focus after an unfocus
- `focusOnNextUnfocus` a bool to set to `true` just before pushing, and which will be set to false once the focus has been requested again.

Here is the adaptation of the code you provided:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  /// Handles the focus state of our text field
  final focusNode = FocusNode();
  
  /// A bool to keep track on whether we should refocus after
  /// unfocus. This will be set to `true` before pushing
  var focusOnNextUnfocus = false;
  
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      // If we no longer have the focus and should refocus, we refocus
      if (!focusNode.hasFocus && focusOnNextUnfocus) {
        focusNode.requestFocus();
        focusOnNextUnfocus = false; // Reset to false once it has been processed
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late BuildContext anotherContext;

    final edit = TextField(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      onChanged: (String value) async {
        if (value.length > 4) {
          // Pop does not unfocus so no worries here
          Navigator.pop(anotherContext);
        } else if (value.length > 3) {
          // Push DOES unfocus, so we need to set focusOnNextUnfocus to true
          focusOnNextUnfocus = true;
          Navigator.of(anotherContext).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
              return Builder(builder: (context) {
                return Another();
              });
            }),
          );
        }
      },
    );

    final scaffold = MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            anotherContext = context;
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '$_counter',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(child: scaffold),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: edit,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Another extends StatelessWidget {
  const Another({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: > Your use case looks really weird but I suppose you have a good reason to follow this setup. 

thank you for your understanding :)
and yeah, I have my reasons.... ))))